# SpecFlow build error "Could not load file or assembly 'TechTalk.SpecFlow'" in VS 2015

Tags: visual-studio-2015, specflow

I am getting below error when try to compile SpecFlow project in VS 2015.

> error Generation error: Could not load file or assembly 'TechTalk.SpecFlow, Version=1.9.0.77, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=0778194805d6db41' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Following are the references I added.

[image]

Comment: what version of Techtalk.Specflow.dll is it referencing? I suspect that one of the specflow extensions requires 1.9.0.77 and you are referencing the latest 2.0.0.0...

Comment: @Sam Holder, Thanks for your reply, Looks like in VS 2015 cannot have other version. Only 2.0.0. is visible when browse.

Comment: @SamHolder Sorry mate. I was able to resolve the issue after switching to SpecFlow 1.9.0. Please add this as the answer

Comment: Was just about to say you could get the specific 1.9 version and that should fix it. I'll add an answer later on. Glad you got it sorted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is most likely caused by one of the extensions still depending on specflow 1.9. You should be able to install that specific version to resolve your issues.

Comment: After resolving compilation issue, when run tests I am getting below error. Looks like it's the same version issue. `[ERROR] Could not load file or assembly 'TechTalk.SpecFlow, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=0778194805d6db4' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. > Could not load file or assembly 'TechTalk.SpecFlow, Version=1.9.0.77, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=0778194805d6db4' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference.`

Answer (score 2):

Could be your temp extensions cache path files are corrupted or missing
C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\Temp\VisualStudioTestExplorerExtensions\

Close visual studio and delete all content from C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\Temp\VisualStudioTestExplorerExtensions
Open visual studio and try running the test.